# Javascript не записывает данные формы в localstorage

Tags: javascript, wordpress, localstorage, contact-form7

Пытаюсь записать данные  формы из Contact form7 через js в localstorage
Но они не записываются записывается лишь одно значение как key=19.04.2018  без value

```
 var inputDate = document.getElementById("date");
 localStorage.setItem("date", inputDate.value);
```

а остальные вообще не работают

```
<script>
 function store(){
     var inputEmail = document.getElementById("email");
     localStorage.setItem("email", inputEmail.value);     
     var inputPlace1 = document.getElementById("place-1");
     localStorage.setItem("place-1", inputPlace1.value);
     var inputPlace2 = document.getElementById("place-2");
     localStorage.setItem("place-2", inputPlace2.value);
     var inputDate = document.getElementById("date");
     localStorage.setItem("date", inputDate.value); 
     var inputDate2 = document.getElementById("date-2");
     localStorage.setItem("date-2", inputDate2.value);
     var inputTime = document.getElementById("time");
     localStorage.setItem("time", inputTime.value);
     var inputTime2 = document.getElementById("time-2");
     localStorage.setItem("time-2", inputTime2.value);
 };
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
        store()

}, false );

</script>
```

Comment: Может какой-то скрипт перезаписыает их?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да код правильный быль просто он запускался до формы проблема была в этом по этому когда он пытался перезаписывать данные он не мог так как формы не существовало когда он запускался мой косяк